# REST API and clients - removing previously seen items - client-side or server-side?

Tags: ios, rest, asp.net-web-api

We have a web-app that uses  Mahout and CF filtering to generate product recommendations, based on users assigning ratings to items.

There is a iOS application that communicates with the webapp through a REST API, and let's users scroll through items, and assign them ratings.

The iOS application will pull a list of ranked products from the webapp - this is the list that is displayed to the user. As the user scrolls through to the end, we request further down the list.

There is also a requirement that the iOS application not show a user products that they've seen before on that specific device.

My question is - how should we be handling this last requirement?

Should each iOS client be maintaining a list of what they've seen before, and simply remove these from the list that it pulls from the server?

Or should the server maintain a state for each client, and remove them from the list before it sends it?

What pros and cons can you see for either approach?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: It depends on the need for storing those history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if the requirement is to not show a user products they've seen before on any device/platform (for example if they used the app on their iphone then ipad/ipod) then you'd definitely have to do it server side (as the app cannot know what the user has seen on other devices unless you are storing it on the server).

Assuming, it is a device specific requirement, I would think your goal would be to minimize (potentially unreliable or slow) network traffic to optimize the iphone experience. Syncing back and forth with the server will require extra network traffic, which may fail at times. Which would lead to a conclusion of client side storage. Unless your users are going to be seeing some huge number of products that would chew up disk space, but I assume the amount of data you store per user would be nominal.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - the uniqueness constraint is specific for each device.